# Django retrieving object instances created during last two weeks

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called Book which has an attribute when_added which stores the time when an instance of the object is created:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # Record the date whenever a new book is added, it will be helpful for showing new arrivals
    when_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null= True)

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.title)
```

I am writing a view that will return me list of books those were added during last two weeks:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

@api_view(['GET'])
def new_arrivals(request, library_id):
    """
    List all new arrival books in a specific library
    """
    d=date.today()-timedelta(days=14)
    print(d)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        books = Book.objects.filter(which_library=library_id)
        books = books.filter(when_added>d)
        print(books)
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here I get a warning saying `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Book.when_added received a naive datetime (2017-11-27 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.` and no book is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have updated my query to books = books.filter(when_added__gte=d), I hope it is correct. Can not cross check as I do not have any older records so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a Timezone aware date?

```
from django.utils import timezone

...
# in the new arrivals view
d=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=14)
```

Comment: I tried books = books.filter(when_added__gte=d) which worked actually as I mentioned in my original comment but not sure because I do not have older records. I will try your answer as well! Thanks :)